# SQL - select based on value existence in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a SQL query to identify wells which do not have A3 events. I am using SQL server.

I have tried multiple ways like checking count, comparing with event A3 but still unable to get what I want.

From below example desired result would be W3 and W4

| Site | Event |
| --- | --- |
| W1 | A1 |
| W1 | A2 |
| W1 | A3 |
| W2 | A1 |
| W2 | A2 |
| W2 | A3 |
| W3 | A1 |
| W3 | A4 |
| W4 | A2 |
| W4 | A4 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregation is one approach:

```sql
SELECT Site
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Site
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Event = 'A3' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

If you really also need to view all sites for matching wells, then put the above into a CTE and use it as a subquery:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Site
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Site
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Event = 'A3' THEN 1 END) = 0
)

SELECT Site, Event
FROM yourTable
WHERE Site IN (SELECT Site FROM cte);
```

Answer (score 2):

**NOT EXISTS** is a very performant approach

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From  YourTable A
 Where not exists ( select 1 
                     from  YourTable T 
                     where T.Well=A.Well and T.[Event]='A3' 
                  )
```

**Results**

```
Well    Event
W3      A1
W3      A4
W4      A2
W4      A4
```

Comment: Just curious about the downvote

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
SELECT DISTINCT site 
FROM table_name 
WHERE site NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT site 
                   FROM table_name 
                   WHERE event = 'A3')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sub-query` will return Sites with A3 event. Hence joining the table using `LEFT JOIN` and filtering for Sites not available in sub-query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Site 
FROM your_table as tbl
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT Site
  FROM your_table
  WHERE Event = 'A3'
) as sq
ON tbl.site=sq.site
WHERE sq.Site IS NULL
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT Well  
FROM test
where Well not in (select Well from tablename where Evt = 'A3');
```

Comment: this will return all wells

Comment: sorry I misread- updated